# How to make navigator work properly?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have React Native app and I'm using `navigator.back()` when I need to go back. 
But I noticed the problem.
For example, If I have three pages A, B, C and I'm starting with A, then I go to B, to C, then go back to B and now if I call `navigator.back()` it leads me to page C, but I expected to see page A.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Here is an example of my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import {
          StyleSheet,
          View,
          StatusBar,
          Navigator
        } from 'react-native'
    ...
        _renderScene (route, navigator) {
            switch (route.name) {
              case RouteName.Home:
                return <Home navigator={navigator} />
              case RouteName.Library:
                return <Library navigator={navigator} />
              case RouteName.BookDetails:
                return <Details navigator={navigator} book={route.passProps.book} />
        default:
                console.error('Encountered unexpected route: ' + route.name)
            }
            return <Home />
          }

...

    export class Library extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
      }

      render(){
       return (
            <View style={styles.library}>
              <Header title={LocalizationService.translate('MyLibrary')} navigator={this.props.navigator} />
              <ScrollView>
                <Accordion
                  ref='accordion'
                  sections={this.state.sections}
                  initiallyActiveSection={0}
                  renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                  renderContent={this._renderContent.bind(this)}
                />
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          )
      }
    }


    export class Header extends Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          title: ''
        }

        this._onClose = this._onClose.bind(this)
      }


      _onClose () {
        let { onClose, navigator } = this.props

        if (onClose) {
          onClose()
        } else {
          navigator && navigator.pop()
        }
      }
    }

    Header.propTypes = {
      title: React.PropTypes.string,
      navigator: React.PropTypes.object,
      onClose: React.PropTypes.func
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like normal behaviour. Are you sure you are going *back* to B and not *forwards* to B?

Comment: when I go from C to B I'm using this method: _goBack () {
    this.props.navigator.back()
  }

Comment: _renderScene (route, navigator) {
    switch (route.name) { case RouteName.bookDetails:
        return <Details navigator={navigator} book={route.passProps.book} />

Comment: any idea? @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the method you're looking for is `.pop()`

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#pop

calling `navigator.pop()` will unmount the component on the top of the stack and go to the previous one.

Comment: I've tried this method, but it doesn't work at all, for some reason. Maybe I have to change something else to use pop().  @john_ryan

Comment: yea if you could the full code example to your question it would probably be helpful in pointing out the issue, for instance how you set up the navigator and how you pass the navigator to the components.

Comment: when you call navigator.pop() does anything show in the logs / does your _renderScene even get called? Also how are you pushing the routes on..it should be something like `navigator.push({'name' : RouteName. Library})` in your Home component

Comment: I'm using this.props.navigator.go({ name: routeName })

Comment: I've changed that to this.props.navigator.push({ name: routeName }), but it doesn't help and nothing write in console.  @john_ryan

Comment: what navigator are you using? i.e. why are you trying to use functions like 'back' and 'go' none of those are in the docs for navigator: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html